# "She managed to successfully start her car" or "She managed to start her car successfully"

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

Are there any rules as to the position of an adverb?

For example:

1. She managed to **successfully** start her car
2. She managed to start her car **successfully**

Can I use either of them?

Comment: There are lots of rules for adverb placement; have a look at any good English grammar book. In this case, 'successfully' in (1) modifies "(to) start her car", whereas in (2) in modifies **either** "(to) start her car" **or** "managed to start her car". This is a syntactic analysis, but the difference in meaning in this case is either extermely small or nothing.

Comment: So yes, you can use either.

Comment: Both sentences seem tautological to me. If you manage to do something, you succeed in doing it so _successfully_ is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Very roughly:

Adverbs don't modify nouns so they shouldn't appear right before nouns where an adjective or article is expected.

Adverbs must appear before the adjective they modify. - *Wait until the temperature is very hot*.

Position is flexible when modifying a verb, though immediately before/after the verb, or at the end of a sentence tends to be preferred.  *I quickly searched for the missing papers* or less often *Quicky I searched for the missing papers*.

For complex sentences, prepositions and conjunctions are a boundary an adverb can't cross to modify a verb--however you can almost always put an adverb at the end or beginning of a sentence or phrase to provide detail on "how" something was done regardless of it's complexity.  So *I searched for the missing papers quickly* works.

In your example the meaning doesn't change much whether *successfully* appears at the start/end of the sentence, or before *managed*/*successfully*.

*Only*, *just*, and *even* are examples of adverbs where the position of one of them and hence what it modifies could change the meaning of the sentence.